# Using an array as index to get values from a dataframe but it misaligned one position forward after a value

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

It happened when I try to add my clustering result into my dataset. I found some rows were set wrong values.
This is just the background.

```
> groups = cutree(hc, 8)
> groups = data.frame(groups)
> scale_data_with_clusters$Substation = as.factor(scale_data_with_clusters$Substation)
> scale_data_with_clusters$clusters = groups[scale_data_with_clusters$Substation,1]
```

It's so weird. Then finally I find where it goes wrong but can't even understand it a little.

```
> scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[218:221]
[1] 523208 523215 523216 523220
535 Levels: 511016 511029 511030 511033 511034 ... 564444
> groups[scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[218:221],1]
[1] 7 7 7 1

> groups['523220',1]
[1] 7
> groups[scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[221],1]
[1] 1
> scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[221]
[1] 523220
> scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[221]=='523220'
[1] TRUE

> groups['523227',1]
[1] 1
> groups[scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[222],1]
[1] 7
> scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[222]
[1] 523227
```

There seems another position forward as this

```
> groups[scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[332:335],1]
[1] 7 5 1 1
> scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[332:335]
[1] 532767 532769 532770 532771
535 Levels: 511016 511029 511030 511033 511034 ... 564444
> groups[c('532767','532769','532770','532771'),1]
[1] 1 7 7 5
> groups[scale_data_with_clusters$Substation[330:333],1]
[1] 1 7 7 5
```

Can anybody tell me why? Thank you!

Comment: `scale_data_with_clusters$Substation` is a factor. `'523220'` may be not the same as `523220`.

Comment: @Bing. But most of values were correctly set. And it just takes the value of some positions after it.